# Consider the following: $x = e^{4t}$, $ y = t + 3$ Eliminate the parameter to find a Cartesian equation of the curve.

Tags: calculus

Consider: $x = e^{4t}$,   $ y = t + 3$

(a) Eliminate the parameter to find a Cartesian equation of the curve.
My answer: [image]
Disregard the one and replace it with three $y=3+\frac{ln(x)}{4}$

(b) Sketch the curve and indicate with an arrow the direction in which the curve is traced as the parameter increases. [image][image]

I thought ln(x) was not defined for negative values?

Comment: Which graph is given as the correct value? You're correct; $\ln x$ is not defined for $x<0$.

Comment: I picked the upper right graph. I guess the upper left is my only option?

Comment: Looks like it (I expanded on it in my answer).

Comment: Compare $(x(0),y(0))$ vs $(x(1),y(1))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've eliminated the bottom two graphs because $\ln x$ is not defined for $x<0$. Now all you have to do is identify the difference between the top two.

The arrow denotes how $x$ and $y$ change with $t$. In the first graph, the arrow tells you that, as $t$ increases,

- $x$ increases $\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}>0\right)$.
- $y$ increases $\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}>0\right)$.

In the second graph, the arrow tells you that, as $t$ increases,

- $x$ decreases.
- $y$ decreases.

Only one of these combinations is true. Now look at the derivatives of your original two parametric equations:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=4e^{4t}>0,\quad\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=1>0$$
This should tell you which of the two graphs is correct. Actually, it differentiates (pun intended) all four graphs from one another.

I suspect, however, that there has been an error in drawing the graphs, because you clearly shouldn't get some finite value for $\ln 0$ - the result of
$$\lim_{x\to0}\ln x$$
is clearly $-\infty$! It may be that the screen resolution isn't good enough, given that the graphs are zoomed out quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

None of the graphs are correct,
because
$\ln(x) \to -\infty$
as $x \to 0$.